# Downgrade bootstrap 4 to 3.3 in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I was trying to search for answers, to find the precautions we need to take while downgrading.

I know bootstrap 3 has 4 scope grid system where as 4 has 5 scope grid system

```
[xs,sm,md,lg,xl]
```

and the way offsets, different classes is changed. If anybody encountered this use case.  please advise your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to re-write the css part completely, we implemented scss for spacing similar  to bootstrap 4. for example `px-3 my-2` etc. Most of the bootstrap 4 classes implemented to reduce the dependency. Bootstrap 3.3 classes has been used in grid system where we are not able to go out of it.